# How to start a new activity on navigation drawer item click

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I've created a custom list navigation drawer in my app and i want it to start a new activity when an item is clicked. I've tried a lot of the solutions suggested in other similar questions but none of them seem to work for me. Here is my Main Activity code.

```
package com.nav.drawer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;




public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawer_layout;
    private ListView listview;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerListener;
    private MyAdapter myadapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        drawer_layout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById (R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer_layout.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);
        drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle (this, drawer_layout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, 0, 0){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }

        };
        drawer_layout.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



        listview = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.left_drawer);
        myadapter = new MyAdapter(this);
        listview.setAdapter(myadapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerListener.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;    
        }
        if (drawerListener.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        selectItem(position);


    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listview.setItemChecked(position, true);
        Intent intent1;
        switch(position){
        case 0:
            intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;

        }

    }

    public void SetTitle(String title){
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);

    }
}

class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context context;
    String [] pages;
    int[] images = {R.drawable.forward_button, R.drawable.forward_button2, R.drawable.forward_button3, R.drawable.forward_button4, R.drawable.forward_button5, R.drawable.forward_button6, R.drawable.forward_button7};



    public MyAdapter (Context context){
        this.context=context;
        pages = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pages);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return pages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return pages[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View row=null;
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row=inflater.inflate (R.layout.row, parent, false);
        }else{
            row=convertView;
        }
        TextView titletextView1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ImageView titleimageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        titletextView1.setText(pages[position]);
        titleimageview.setImageResource(images[position]);
        return row;
    }

}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what error do you get on click,,,Davie

Comment: I don't get any errors, The app runs successfully but nothing happens when I click the item

Comment: check and debug your code,switch(position){
        case 0:
            intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;

        }  whether it reaches in this block or not...

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer,use this link

Comment: the code reaches in the block

Comment: had u declared NewActivity.java in manifest??

Comment: I had not declared the NewActivity, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the manifest file Davie, had u declared NewActivity.java in manifest??

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.